# How to concatenate database results in GraphQL using JoinMonster?

Tags: graphql

I'm using `join-monster` in a project, but there is a problem I couldn't figure out its cause up to now. I have 27 databases with the same structure. I need to run a query in all of them and concatenate all the results in one single response. My `resolve` property is like so:

```
  resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => {
    return joinMonster(resolveInfo, {}, sql => {
      const pending = Object.keys(databases).map(async (key) => {
        let conn = await databases[key]()
        conn.query = promisify(conn.query)

        return conn.query(sql).then(result => {
          conn.detach()
          return result
        })
      })

      return Promise.all(pending)
        .then(values => [].concat.apply([], values))
        .catch(error => { throw error })
    })
```

`databases` is an object in that each key represents a database connection. As you can see, I'm executing the same query in all databases. All the results are being returned pretty well. But when I execute a GraphQL query, the following result is being returned:

```
{
  "data": {
    "offices": [
      {
        "id": "21300380",
        "name": "Portela Lima e Colen Advogados",
        "address": null,
        "city": null,
        "state": null,
        "clients": [
          {
            "clientcode": "COLIN301",
            "email": "controladoria@plcadvogados.com.br"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my database, the office `21300380` has at least 300 clients, but in the GraphQL response, a single client is being returned. What am I doing wrong here?